# Why are implied covariance matrices in SEM supposed to be nonpositive definite?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I read at [this site](https://krmunger.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/amos_sem-manual2.pdf) some tips about what to do if the implied matrix is nonpositive definite. However, it's not clear to me why this is meant to be a problem.

Is the reasoning just:
- The population covariance matrix can't be nonpositive definite.
- The model implied matrix is meant to represent the population covariance matrix.
- Therefore the model implied matrix isn't properly representing the population covariance matrix.

Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another (pragmatic) reason. To calculate chi-square (using ML) you need to invert the implied covariance matrix. If the implied matrix isn't positive definite, you can't invert it so you can't do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If the covariance matrix is non-positive definite we could end up with a negative variance for the portfolio.

The variance of a portfolio is calculated using variance = x' * C * x  formula, where C is the covariance matrix and x is a vector of fractional weights (positive or negative) of portfolio's constituents.

A positive definite covariance matrix guarantees that x' * C * x > 0

Comment: What variance s negative?